# How do I output a line graph with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, graph, plot, rubygems, gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot gem to create a graph.

As of now, I have data being output:

```
x1, x2, x3 ... x100
```

I am able to do this by instantiating an object from a class.

```
MyClass.numbers
```

I want to output these numbers in a graph. Should I use gnuplot or another gem? How would I implement this using gnuplot?

Comment: Your favorite internet search engine is your fried when searching for ruby and gnuplot. You can either use a gnuplot gem or call gnuplot by hand (e.g. https://coderwall.com/p/otpcqa). I find gnuplot an okay solution, its stable and available. Sure enough, the default graph will not be very fancy, but functional. Did you check the README of the gnuplot gem you are using?

Comment: @Felix i did search on Google. Most seem to be Rails specific. I did read the documentation for gnu. (It wasn't well explained)

Comment: The link i gave is not rails specific and the README for example at https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot gives examples. The search took 3 seconds.